# How do I compare a dataset versus adcomputer records?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to compare a dataset which i got with a simple SQL query like this

```
$qry = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT Name, IsCompliant,LatestEntry,ComputerManufacturerName,ComputerModelName,OperatingSystemName,MachinesUsersNames,ErrorInfoName FROM ComplianceCore.MachinesComplianceView WHERE isCompliant='false'", $conn)
$adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $qry
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataset) | Out-Null
```

The issue is i am now trying to get the OUs for each computer by trying to compare the names with the AD cmdlet.

```
get-adcomputer -filter * -properties * | Where-Object { $_.Name -like $dataset.tables.name }
```

Any idea on what is going on since i receive 0 results.

Comment: try  `get-adcomputer -filter * -properties * | Where-Object { $_.Name -like $($dataset.tables.name) }`

Comment: @Adis1102 No results, do i have to run through each list of names with a foreach or does the cmdlet do that for me?

Comment: you are right, I missed that part. You need to use a loop. As far as I understood you want to compare each ADComupter and not the list you get from `Get-adcomputer...`

Comment: I want to make sure that every name in dataset.tables runs against the get-adcomputer names. How do i best start off with that i suppose that i have to make 2 foreach loops? Isn't there something more efficient?

Comment: If you are not using wildcards, `-like` is likely not the correct operator. If you are comparing one value to another value exactly, use `-eq`. If you are comparing one value against many values (like in a list), then use `-in`. If you are comparing one value against many partial values, you either need to construct a regex string with alternations or loop through each value using `-like` and wildcards.

Comment: Won't the script run an incredibly long time if i loop through each value string with -like and wildcards? @AdminOfThings

Comment: @claeys potentially, yes. What does `$dataset.tables.name` contain?

Comment: A set of data from the bitlocker DB: name, errorcode, OS, etc

Comment: If `$dataset.tables.name` contains computer names, I would switch from using `-like` to `-in` in your command.